# Is it correct to say "I hardly remember myself being at your age"

Tags: sentence-construction

Lately I used this sentence in a conversation, but somehow it didn't feel right. 
I was wondering if any of these

> I hardly remember myself being at your age

or

> I hardly remember how it was back in your age

are correct?

Comment: Try "I hardly remember what it was like to be your age."

Comment: I hardly remember being your age.

Comment: I hardly remember anything, much less being your age  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two of the comments above are correct ways of expressing what your first sentence might have been intended to say.

> I hardly remember what it was like to be your age. - Robusto

This one refers to the experience of being at a particular age. Maybe the speaker can remember things that happened at that age, but cannot remember how they felt about what happened. I can, for example, remember my first kiss: how old I was, who it was with, where we were, etc, but I can't remember at all how I felt at the time. Did I enjoy it? Was I nervous? I have no recollection at all.

> I hardly remember being your age. - Jeff Morrow

This sentence is less specific, and suggests that the speaker can remember very little at all about being that age: events, locations, people, things, plus emotions, experiences etc, have all disappeared into the mist.

Your second sentence can, with minor adjustments, be used to describe another situation:

> I hardly remember how it was when I was your age

This sentence relates to the situation or environment for children when the speaker was young. For example, if the speaker is over the three-score-years and ten, they would probably think that parents were stricter back then, and that children had more freedom to explore on their own, as paedophiles were unheard of.